# bitmonero and simplewallet error cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:148 max_out exceeded

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod

I have a problem in bitmonero node and simplewallet. When I'm starting both I'm getting the same error:

```
ERROR /DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:148 max_out exceeded
```

I'm using Monero 'Hydrogen Helix' (v0.9.4.0-release).

I found some github discussion: 
https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/861
and
https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/888

In both links it is said that this issue is fixed but I'm using newest code. Can someone tell if it's something to worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the release version of 0.9.4 - Hydrogen Helix, which equates to the binaries available on the [official website](https://getmonero.org/downloads/). This release version was tagged on commit [a42e19e (PR #780)](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/a42e19e1b7943ca70147eb1d86f57087981b235b). Thus, the changes (and fixes) made after that are not included in the version you are using and are only available if you compile from master. If you compile yourself, it will show you the latest commit you compiled from. Thus, if you would compile yourself at this moment, you would get version [`v0.9.4.0-011e42f`](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/011e42f3377b9fa727c419113e683ffada15ae88).

Comment: Great. This is what I was thinking. Should I worry about this problem?

Comment: According to the [comment](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/861#issuecomment-224979461) of MoneroMooo you can ignore it for now.